# How do I get MVCSiteMap to include all my custom route

Tags: asp.net, routes, mvcsitemapprovider

I want to use the route attribute defined in my C# files for create the xml site map (MVCSiteMap) file like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("{culture}/Registration/Person")]
public partial class PersonController : BaseController
{
   [HttpPost]
   [Route("Step1")]
   public ActionResult StartStep1() {}
}
```

and create an xml file like this:

```
 <mvcSiteMapNode title="Registration" controller="Person" action="Index" >
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Registration Person" route="Step1" controller="Person" action="Index" />
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

But route attribute is ignored and the result was:

```
Additional information: A route named 'Step1' could not be found in the route collection.
```

My web.config file is configured like this:

```
 <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_IncludeRootNodeFromSiteMapFile" value="true" />
<add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_AttributesToIgnore" value="" />
<add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_CacheDuration" value="5" />
<add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_UseExternalDIContainer" value="false" />
<add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_ScanAssembliesForSiteMapNodes" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to use the route attribute defined in my C# files for create the xml site map (MVCSiteMap) file

You can't.

The purpose of nodes is to define a parent-child relationship between different controller actions. Route attributes do not provide a way to do this, so there is no way to automatically include every possible match for a route in a `.sitemap` file or define the hierarchy.

You must provide a node configuration to fill in the missing piece that MVC does not provide. You can provide the node configuration one of 4 ways:

1. [`.sitemap` XML file](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-in-XML)
2. [MvcSiteMapNodeAttribute](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-using-.NET-attributes)
3. [Dynamic Node Providers](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-using-IDynamicNodeProvider)
4. Implement `ISiteMapNodeProvider` and inject your implementation using external DI (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19838084/how-to-implement-custom-sitemapnodeprovider#19856898) for details)

I think that the option that is most similar to what you want is to use `MvcSiteMapNodeAttribute`.

```
[RoutePrefix("{culture}/Registration/Person")]
public partial class PersonController : BaseController
{
    // NOTE: This assumes you have defined a node on your 
    // Home/Index action with a key "HomeKey"
    [MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Registration", 
        Key = "RegistrationKey", ParentKey = "HomeKey")]
    public ActionResult Index() {}

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Step1")]
    [MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Registration Person", 
        Key = "RegistrationPersonKey", ParentKey = "RegistrationKey")]
    public ActionResult StartStep1() {}
}
```

> Additional information: A route named 'Step1' could not be found in the route collection.

The route attribute is to identify a registered route by name, not by URL. So to make your configuration work, you would need to name your route.

```
[Route("Step1", Name = "TheRouteName")]
```

And then use the same name in your node configuration.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Registration Person" route="TheRouteName" controller="Person" action="Index" />
```